# Error generating query execution plan in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

When I am trying to get a estimated query execution plan for any query in SSMS, I get the below error message:

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. Access is denied.

I am using SQL Server 2008 with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version 10.50.2500.0.

Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you installed a previous CTP version of SQL Server Service Pack 2 and then upgraded only the DM Add-ins. If this is correct, you will need to

- Uninstall the DM Add-ins
- Install the SQL Server SP 2 (http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2005/downloads/servicepacks/sp2.mspx)
- Install the version of add-ins coming with SP2 (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=7c76e8df-8674-4c3b-a99b-55b17f3c4c51&DisplayLang=en)